BIND zones added manually to config file not appearing in Webmin
I‘m just in the process of rebuilding a system which includes BIND and Webmin.
Zone files for BIND are on an external disk, which worked fine on the previous setup.
After installing the server from scratch, I went into webmin and edited /etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones, adding the entries for the zone files as they were on the old setup, then restarted BIND.
If I query one of these zones (using nslookup and first setting server 127.0.0.1), I can resolve names in these zones.
However, Webmin tells me there are no DNS zones defined for this name server. Restarting BIND through Webmin, reloading Webmin modules and even restarting the server does not work.
It seems to be just Webmin that is having issues, as querying the zone works. How do I get these zone files to show up in Webmin?

Upon closer examination, I noticed that BIND had some pre-configured zones (including 127.in-addr.arpa and local), which exhibited the same behavior. Name resolution worked but the zones were not showing up in Webmin.
I commented out my own zone files in the config and retried – still nothing.
I tried creating a new zone named test using the Webmin UI. After that zone was added, the default zones appeared next to it. My own zones also appeared after uncommenting the respective sections in the config file.
So apparently, that is a bug in Webmin (which I just created) causing a freshly set up system to not show any zones until the first zone is added in the GUI.
